# Why can I call a function that accepts a reference with a reference of a reference?

Tags: rust

As far as I know, the `&` symbol creates a reference. But using `sum_vec` with or without `&` will both compile. I just want to know what is happening when I do `let s1 = sum_vec(&v1);`. will this create a reference of a reference ?

```
fn main() {
    // Don't worry if you don't understand how `fold` works, the point here is that an immutable reference is borrowed.
    fn sum_vec(v: &Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
        return v.iter().fold(0, |a, &b| a + b);
    }
    // Borrow two vectors and sum them.
    // This kind of borrowing does not allow mutation to the borrowed.
    fn foo(v1: &Vec<i32>, v2: &Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
        // do stuff with v1 and v2
        let s1 = sum_vec(v1);//This wil also complile with &. Is this optional?.
        let s2 = sum_vec(v2);
        // return the answer
        s1 + s2
    }

    let v1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let v2 = vec![4, 5, 6];

    let answer = foo(&v1, &v2);
    println!("{}", answer);
    println!("{}", v1.len());
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Don%27t%20worry%20if%20you%20don%27t%20understand%20how%20%60fold%60%20works%2C%20the%20point%20here%20is%20that%20an%20immutable%20reference%20is%20borrowed.%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20sum_vec(v%3A%20%26Vec%3Ci32%3E)%20-%3E%20i32%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20v.iter().fold(0%2C%20%7Ca%2C%20%26b%7C%20a%20%2B%20b)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Borrow%20two%20vectors%20and%20sum%20them.%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20This%20kind%20of%20borrowing%20does%20not%20allow%20mutation%20to%20the%20borrowed.%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20foo(v1%3A%20%26Vec%3Ci32%3E%2C%20v2%3A%20%26Vec%3Ci32%3E)%20-%3E%20i32%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20do%20stuff%20with%20v1%20and%20v2%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20s1%20%3D%20sum_vec(v1)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20s2%20%3D%20sum_vec(v2)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20return%20the%20answer%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20s1%20%2B%20s2%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20v1%20%3D%20vec!%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20v2%20%3D%20vec!%5B4%2C%205%2C%206%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20answer%20%3D%20foo(%26v1%2C%20%26v2)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20answer)%3B%0A%7D%0A))

Comment: Note: it is more idiomatic (and flexible) to take a `&[T]` argument rather than a `&Vec<T>` argument. The only difference between a `Vec` and slice is that the latter, when mutable, allows adding/removing elements. Since when immutable there is no difference, using the lowest common denominator allows more code to call into the function.

Comment: @MatthieuM. It's like we [made a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423) so we didn't have to repeat that all the time ^_^

Comment: why the dislike ?

Comment: @CodeJoy: A mystery of StackOverflow; don't worry too much about a single vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and No. Rust will create a reference to a reference (since you asked explicitly for it with the `&` operator), and then immediately "autoderef" it again to fit the target type. The optimizer will then eliminate that intermediate reference.

Comment: And Clippy will warn you that you've typed something silly.